# How to change URL without affecting SEO

Tags: url

Please note that I have created a forum by installing the phpbb software in bluehost server in a folder named (lets give an example) "examplefolder" and thus the URL of a post is:
`www.example.com/examplefolder/viewtopic.php`
taking into consideration that this post appeared at first positions of google, bing, etc search enginees (after searching for the topic of this post), could you please let me know if the search engines' position of this post will be changed in case that I will change the name of "examplefolder" to something else.